# React-native | Disable spellCheck red underline in inputField | android Environment

Tags: android, react-native

Red underline of input is still coming after giving below properties

```
spellCheck={false}
autoCorrect={false}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the spellcheck attribute on TextInput only works for iOS. I believe that Android spell checking is controlled through the device's settings. So, I would suggest you try disabling spell check on the device first, and give it another go.